# Disable physics engine

Tags: physics

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I was wondering if it is possible to disable completely the physics simulation and have only kinematic simulation (something like OpenRAVE).

Thx,
Enrico

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6325/disable-physics-engine/) by [Enrico Mingo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/507/enrico-mingo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 121 on 2014-05-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here is a solution: https://answers.ros.org/question/218744/gazebo-disable-physics-or-enable-kinematics-through-codecommand-line/

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2020-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0